# What type of key - value list would not impose a number to each element?

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin

There's probably a better way to phrase my question.

I have an object that one of its elements should be a list of key and value pairs.
My problem is that when I save the object to firebase, the list saves each element under a node with a number key like an array.
I don't want to have that node, I want the key- value to be directly under the parent.

In my example you could see under images what I am talking about.

I've tried to define the "image" element as `mutableListOf<Map<String, Boolean>>` or `mutableCollectionOf<Map<String, Boolean>>`

[image]

Comment: try saving as `mutableListOf(Pair(key, value))`

Comment: I've tried that but it did it even worse. Under the number 0 I had a node called first with the value of the string and a node called second with the value of the Boolean

Comment: what you want to achieve is like `body -> images -> key: value` ?

Comment: @P.Juni yes. I think I solved it by using just a mapOf. I will post my solution here soon